# Is there a way to get godmode in Watch_Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm currently catching up on my back catalog of games. One of the games that I want to at least finish the main storyline of is Watch_Dogs, but I find the combat too challenging. I'm thinking about enabling Godmode in some way, like I did with GTA 5 and Far Cry 3 and 4, but I'm not sure how.

Ideally, I want a method that is enabled automatically as soon as the game starts.

Note: I don't play multiplayer and have disabled the online integrations in the game.

Comment: Afaik cheating in this game will get you banned from uplay, as it has online interactions even if you disable them.

Comment: @ardaozkal when they're talking about "banned from uplay", does that mean i won't be able to play ANY of my uplay games, or just Watch_dogs? Because while I don't really care about being banned from playing Watch_Dogs online, I do care when that means I can't play Assassin's Creed anymore. Does that same rule apply for Far Cry 3 and 4? I played those with Godmode enabled, although that was through a config file edit

Comment: @ardaozkal Also, this was discussed in chat earlier today: The license says "(iii) create, use and/or distribute “auto”, “trainer”, “script” or “macro” computer programs or other “cheat” or “hack” programs or software applications for this Product (whether in an online multiplayer game or in a single player game over the internet or in local area network);" from which we assumed that if you don't go online (so play without an internet connection), you should be safe, since it specifically only calls out singleplayer "over the internet or in local area network".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking Ubisoft about their policy on Watch_Dogs cheats with the game blocked from the Internet, this is the answer:

> Bedankt voor het in contact treden met Ubisoft Klantenservice met betrekking tot Watch Dogs.
>
> Mijn excuses voor dit late antwoord, wij ervaren op dit moment extreme drukte.
>
> Het spijt mij te horen dat u problemen ervaart met de moeilijkheid in Watch Dogs en dat dit uw speelervaring vermindert.
>
> Helaas moet ik u meedelen dat er een strikte 'No cheat'-policy geldt bij Ubisoft. Om geen mazen in het net te laten is beslist dit door te trekken over de gehele lijn op al onze spellen zowel online als offline. Ik moet u dus zeggen dat wij, conform onze condities, cheaten niet toelaten of officieel ondersteunen.
>
> Mijn excuses voor het ongemak.
>
> Indien u vragen heeft aarzel dan niet om met ons in contact te treden, zodat wij u verder kunnen helpen.

Translated: We have a strict no-cheat policy at Ubisoft. To not have any loopholes, the decision was made to apply this policy across the board, on all our games, both online and offline. So I have to tell you that we do not allow or officially support cheating.

I'm currently writing a followup to ask what steps I can take to help with my issue, without breaking their policy.

---

After asking for clarification, it appears the CS rep misunderstood my followup question. He clarified they only disallow 3rd party cheats. If you use a cheat the developer included themselves, it's fine. However, because such cheats are not officially supported, CS reps are not allowed to say if such cheats are in the game.

Answer (score 2):

[WeMod offers cheats for *Watch_Dogs*](https://community.wemod.com/t/watch-dogs-cheats-and-trainer-for-steam/12712)

> 1. Unlimited Health
> 2. Unlimited Ammo
> 3. No Reload
> 4. Infinite Money
> 5. Unlimited Battery
> 6. Max Wanted Level
> 7. No Wanted Level
> 8. Invisibility (Missions)
> 9. Unlimited Focus

I think this is an early listing of the cheats, with more available in the current version, but I'm away from my desktop.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing when I played the game again in 2020.